# Jquery function that runs after an user has pasted a Youtube link in an input (Ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is the HTML from where the url value will be extracted.

```
<p align="center">Youtube video</p>

<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-3 large-2 columns">

    <span class="prefix">http://</span>

    </div>

    <div class="small-9 large-10 columns">

    <input type="url" id="thread_url" placeholder="Youtube link...">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="dynamicPreview">
    <iframe width="320" height="240" src="" frameborder="0" class="hide"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is the php function for getting the Video id from a youtube link.

```
    public function getYoutubeVideoId($url) {

    $pattern = '%^# Match any youtube URL
    (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
    (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
    (?:             # Group host alternatives
      youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
      (?:           # Group path alternatives
        /embed/     # Either /embed/
      | /v/         # or /v/
      | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
      )             # End path alternatives.
    )               # End host alternatives.
    ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
    $%x';

    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if (false !== $result) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
```

How do I get a Jquery script to run , after an user has pasted a Youtube link , and how the ajax function must look in order for it to run automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the text is changed so:

```
<p align="center">Youtube video</p>

<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-3 large-2 columns">

    <span class="prefix">http://</span>

    </div>

    <div class="small-9 large-10 columns">

    <input type="url" id="thread_url" placeholder="Youtube link...">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="dynamicPreview">
    <iframe width="320" height="240" src="" frameborder="0" class="hide"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').delegate('#thread_url','keyup',function() {

            $.post( "youtube_function.php", {url: $(this).val() })
               .done(function( data ) {
                if(data) {
                   //Its a youtube link
                }
             });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: i think youre mixing php with js , the getYoutubeVideoId is not callable from that point, also i would check for change event, to not fire hundret times

Comment: Yeah realized, mostly read the function name. will update answer in a min.

Comment: So , do I add this like a script ? <script>Your code</script> underneath the <input> ?